# What is a UEFI bootable Ubuntu USB?

Tags: boot, uefi, live-usb, csm

Previously I have a Ubuntu 16.04 live USB. Now I have a new computer with Windows 10 installed. Since it uses UEFI firmware, I also have to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Do I need an UEFI bootable Ubuntu 16.04 live USB? Is my previous live USB not UEFI bootable?

Boot configurations:

Boot\CSM (Compatibility Support Module)
  Boot from storage devices = UEFI driver first
  Boot device control = UEFI and Legacy OPROM
  Fast Boot = disabled

Boot sequence
  option 1 = UEFI SanDisk blablabla (This is the Ubuntu 16.04 .iso USB.)
  option 2 = blablabla (This is Windows 10.)
  option 3 = disabled
  option 4 = disabled

Comment: All recent Ubuntu installers work for both UEFI & BIOS. It just is how you choose to boot from UEFI/BIOS is then how it installs. From UEFI boot menu you should see two USB boot options one UEFI: flash and the other flash where flash is name or label of your USB flash drive. You may have to turn on allow USB boot in UEFI settingsl. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI &  http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi You may want the latest Ubuntu 16.04.3

Comment: Boot\CSM(Compatibility Support Module):

Boot from storage Devices = UEFI driver first;
Boot Device Control = UEFI and Legacy OPROM;
Fast Boot = disabled;
4.Boot

Sequere Boot
option 1 = UEFI SanDisk blablabla(This is the Ubuntu1604 iso USB)
option 2 = blablabla(This is Windows10)
option 3 = disabled
option 4 = disabled

Comment: This is my boot configuration, I still have error,and therefore I am wondering is that possible, choosing iso Partition scheme and BIOS mode as BIOS&UEFI is the problem.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

This is why I try to make a UEFI bootable USB

Comment: On my Asus motherboard, the UEFI & BIOS boot setting with UEFI first only booted in BIOS mode. I had to use UEFI only setting to boot flash drive in UEFI mode. I was using a standard configured flash drive that would boot in either mode, and it just kept booting in BIOS mode until I changed setting. Did not know back then about UEFI only, but not sure even then if that would have worked.

Comment: If you use a **cloning** tool to create the USB boot drive, it will be bootable both in UEFI and BIOS mode. The Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator in 16.04 LTS and newer versions is a cloning tool. Also `gnome-disks` and `mkusb` can clone from the iso file to a USB pendrive. In Windows you can use Win32DiskImager or Rufus (in dd mode).